# Como decrementar data com while no sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Meu script tem um comando `while` que **faz 18 interações** e estou tentado customizar, porém sem sucesso, preciso deixa-lo menos complexo e mais eficiente:

```
declare @i int = 1;
declare @MesAno varchar(7)

while (@i <= 18)
begin   
    if(@i = 1)
    begin
        set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE()), 2), SPACE(1), '0')
        --aqui faço algo
    end
    if(@i = 2)
    begin
        set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-1, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
        --aqui faço algo
    end 
    /*set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-2, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-3, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-4, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-5, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-6, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-7, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-8, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-9, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-10, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-11, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE()), 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-1, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-2, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-3, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-4, 2), SPACE(1), '0')*/
    if(@i = 2)
    begin
        set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate())-1)+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())-5, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
        --aqui faço algo
    end
end
```

Preciso substituir o código acima por algo parecido com o código abaixo que estou tentando implementar:

```
declare @i int = 1;
declare @MesAno varchar(7)
while (@i <= 18)
begin   
    set @MesAno = CONVERT (VARCHAR(4),YEAR(Getdate()))+ '-'+ REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE())+'-'+@i, 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    --aqui faço algo
    select @MesAno
    --...
set @i = @i + 1;
end
```

**O problema é o jeito que faço concatenação da variável:** `+'-'+@i`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Segue...

Uma possível solução

```
USE MASTER
GO

DECLARE @I INT = 1 ;
DECLARE @ANOMES INT 

WHILE ( @I <= 18)
BEGIN 
    SET @ANOMES = FORMAT(DATEADD(MM,-@I,GETDATE()), 'yyyyMM' )

    PRINT @I 
    PRINT @ANOMES
    

    SET @I += 1;
END
```